# Does the USB Bluetooth Adapter need to resync when moving to another device?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a headset that I use on two devices.  Each time I wish to switch from one device to the other (about once a week), I need to resync the bluetooth to that device.

I'd like to stop having to do that and I'd rather not buy two headsets but am more interested however in possibly purchasing one USB Bluetooth Adapter and move that instead, as needed.

My question is, will that work?  Can I purchase one single bluetooth USB adapter and move that instead, and still have the headset be properly sync'd with each device as I move it from one to the other?

Comment: When you connect to headset it pairs with your device (PC, smartphone, other). During pairing your headset and PC (lets call it PC) create something known as link key. The link key is stored inside headset memory and by PC's OS. So when you moving headset to other device PC (or to smarphone) it needs to use other link key. However, headsets usually can store only one link key so you have to re-pair it.

Comment: Question is...  is the link-key hardware based, like a MAC address?  ie...  computer to computer-adapter, headset to headset-adapter, but computer-adapter to headset-adapter via a hardware link between the two adapters?

I'm pretty sure your answer is that it will not work, just trying to get more clarity.

Comment: No, it is no hardware based and generated internally during pairing process. There are devices that can pair with not just a single device (like PCs) so they can keep more than single link key. However headsets/handsfree/etc usually stores only single link key becaus eof small memory and because of security.